# Change 0 to NULL in Cloudera

Tags: sql, cloudera-cdh

I am looking for a solution to change all attributes of a variable from 0 values into NULL or vice versa to keep the data set conform
For example:

```
everyday_banking
0
NULL
NULL
NULL
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

how can this be done within the create table statement as I have many of them

```
CREATE TABLE new
AS SELECT 
customer_number, 
everyday_banking, 
insurance
from old;
```

Using Cast or how would that need to be done in Cloudera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE new AS SELECT customer_number, COALESCE(everyday_banking,0), insurance from old;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use an update statement for this, *after* you have created and populated your table.  To replace all NULLs with zero, you may try:

```
UPDATE new
SET everyday_banking = COALESCE(everyday_banking, 0);
```

To replace zeroes with NULL, use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE new
SET everyday_banking = CASE WHEN everyday_banking = 0 THEN NULL END;
```